# addTarget from external class

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing this problem: I would like to assign an action for a button created runtime, I'm using this custom class:

```
import UIKit

class SubViewManager: NSObject {
var button = UIButton()
```

Then I have the function to add the button in the view:

```
frame.addSubview(button)
```

And the function for assign the action:

```
func setButtonAction(sender: UIButton!, buttonAction: Selector) {
    button.addTarget(self, action: buttonAction, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}
```

Now in the ViewController Class I call the SubViewManager object like this:

```
var newSubView:SubViewManager!
```

Then in a procedure I'm doing:

```
newSubView.addButton(...//Dimension and details//...)
newSubView.setButtonAction(newSubView.button, buttonAction: "save")
```

And here I have the problem, this error appair in the console:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f92f9694140

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I noticed that if I initialize the object directly in the function where I call the `.setButtonAction` it works, but I can't declare in the same function because I need it in multiple functions!

**RE-EDIT**: When i do the `.addTarget` method I would like to run a ViewController Class's procedure but it runs the SubViewManager procedure which don't exist, that's the why of the error, but I don't know how to run the ViewController Class procedure while calling the `.addTarget` in an external class.

Comment: where's your `save()` function?

Comment: In the ViewController Class

Comment: is it `private` by any chance? or does it have any arguments? Please update OP with the function signature.

Comment: I update the answer, read the edit please and tell me if you need more infos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its crashing because in your code the target that you set to handle the button's action event is the SubViewManager instance ('self' inside setButtonAction method)

```
func setButtonAction(sender: UIButton!, buttonAction: Selector) {
    button.addTarget(self, action: buttonAction, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}
```

But the actually object where you implemented the save function is ViewController class.

You can try modify the parameter of the setButtonAction method to pass the target that will implemented the button action instead of unused  `sender : UIButton!`  because you already call addButton method and has button property to point to it already.
Try something like this

```
func setButtonAction(target: AnyObject! , buttonAction: Selector) {
    button.addTarget(target, action: buttonAction, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}
```

Then pass in the viewController when you calling the setButtonAction method

```
newSubView.setButtonAction(self, buttonAction: "save")
```

where `self` is instance of the ViewController class that implemented the save function.